# Подскажите компонент 2 взаимоисключающих multiselect

Tags: reactjs

Нужен такой компонент чтобы с 2-мя выпадающими списками множественного выбора. Если опция выбрана в одном, во втором её удалять или делать неактивной. Подскажите кто сталкивался с подобным, спасибо

Comment: писать свой, на выбор селекта менять стейт, из которого будут браться опции

Comment: Использовать компонент селекта, где варианты задаются в виде массива, например https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select
При выборе в одном селекте, пробежаться по массиву вариантов второго селекта и исключить значения, которые выбраны в первом